# Scala Spark - Count occurrences of a specific string in Dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, aggregate, window-functions

How can I count the occurrences of a String in a `df` Column using Spark partitioned by `id`?

e.g. Find the value `"test"` in column `"name"` of a `df`

In SQL would be:

```
 SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'test' THEN 1 else 0 END) over window AS cnt_test
  FROM
    mytable
 WINDOW window AS (PARTITION BY id)
```

I've tried using `map( v => match { case "test" -> 1.. })`

and things like:

```
def getCount(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val dfCnt = df.agg(
          .withColumn("cnt_test", 
            count(col("name")==lit('test'))
)
```

Is this an expensive operation? What could be the best approach to check for occurrences of a specific string and then perform an action `(sum, max, min, etc)`?

thanks

Comment: does any answer helped you? If yes, please accept it

Answer (score 8):

You can use `groupBy` + `agg` in spark; Here `when($"name" == "test", 1)` transforms `name` column to `1` if `name == 'test'`, `null` otherwise, and `count` gives count of non null values:

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(count(when($"name" === "test", 1)).as("cnt_test"))
```

---

*Example*:

```
val df = Seq(("a", "joe"), ("b", "test"), ("b", "john")).toDF("id", "name")
df.groupBy("id").agg(count(when($"name" === "test", 1)).as("cnt_test")).show
+---+--------+
| id|cnt_test|
+---+--------+
|  b|       1|
|  a|       0|
+---+--------+
```

Or similar to your sql queries:

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(sum(when($"name" === "test", 1).otherwise(0)).as("cnt_test")).show
+---+--------+
| id|cnt_test|
+---+--------+
|  b|       1|
|  a|       0|
+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate your SQL, you can just also Window-functions in Spark as well:

```
def getCount(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

  df.withColumn("cnt_test",
      sum(when($"name" === "test", 1).otherwise(0)).over(Window.partitionBy($"id"))
    )
}
```